# How to use GCP service account in Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Platform service account with domain-wide authority. I can add it to a Google Analytics API call from my terminal and it works correctly. However, I would like to run that same script as a Google Cloud Function and reference the service account in GCP without including the client_secret_service_account.json file (like below) in the repository or anywhere outside of GCP. Is that possible?

```
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'client_secret_service_account.json'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  In order to use a service account anywhere, you need to be able to have its file (or at least the file's contents as a JSON string) at the location where the code is running so you can initialize the SDKs.

Comment: Could I ask that you have a good read at the following and see if that helps ... https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, I have the json file for the service account. But I am trying to access that account directly in GCP without having to store the file in a repository for the Function.

Comment: @Kolban Yes, good reference. That is for a default service account and I am not using that. I am using a non-default domain-wide service account. Functions use the default service account by default, I'm not sure about non-default ones.

Comment: You need to have the file somehow available at runtime in order to use its credentials.  Storing it somewhere else that doesn't also require some service account or credentials only increases security risks.  It's not advisable.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thats exactly my point. The service account credentials are already stored in GCP IAM. I should not have to have them in a separate file in a Function.

Comment: @analyticsPierce ... howdy again.  If we look in the Docs link posted earlier and look for "Updating the identity of an existing function" ... does this not allow us to specify an alternate service account that the function will run as?

Comment: So you're suggesting that deployed code should have unconditional access to all registered service accounts in the project, which in turn means that the code has unconditional access to everything that those accounts have access to?

Comment: @DougStevenson what is your point here? if you are not offering constructive suggestions maybe the best thing to do is not participate.

Comment: @Kolban  ah right, good suggestion. I'll try that.

Comment: It just sounds like to me that you are trying to bypass normal security measures. You are free to ignore what I'm saying if I'm unclear about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now reference the service account when deploying Cloud Functions. Check [documentation for gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--service-account).

When using GCP console, expand "Advanced options" to  inform the service account